# Calculate the distance between points and contour lines

Tags: qgis, gdal, elevation, contour

Is there a way to calculate the distance between points and contour lines with a minimum elevation value ?

Context:
I have data from vegetation plots in island that is mostly flat, with the exception of the sand dunes close to the shores. I need to know which plots are located closer to a dune (thus more "sheltered") and each ones are distant. My plots are points and the contour lines were extracted from a DGM of resolution 1m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either select all contour lines above your specified threshold, or create polygons representing the dunes, then run `join by nearest` with the plots as first input and the selected lines/dune-polygons as second input. All attributes of the nearest line/dune will be added to the plots, including a distance.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.